# Two Alertviews on one view

Tags: objective-c, uialertview

---

EDIT:

Problem Solved ==> Simply giving a tag solved the problem.

---

I have the following problem:

On a view I have two UIalertviews:

```
NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Users must enter this code to join the meeting: %@", meetingCode];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Meeting code"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Copy to clipboard", nil];
    [alert show];
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
{
    NSLog(@"Code not copied");
}
else
{
    UIPasteboard *pasteboard = [UIPasteboard generalPasteboard];
    pasteboard.string = meetingCode;
    NSLog(@"Code copied"); 
}
}
```

and this one:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {

    AgendaModel* agenda = _meeting.agenda[indexPath.row] ;
    NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:agenda.id,@"id",agenda.name,@"name", nil];
    NSString *message = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Are you sure that you want to delete : %@?", agenda.name];

    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Warning"
                                                    message:message
                                                   delegate:self
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Delete", nil];
    [alert show];

    NSString *delete_url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"RestAgendas/delete.json"];
    [_meeting.agenda removeObject:agenda];
    [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    [JSONAPI getWithPath:delete_url andParams:dict completion:^(id json, JSONModelError *err) {
        NSLog(@"%@", json);
    }];
}
}

- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
if(buttonIndex == [alertView cancelButtonIndex])
{
    NSLog(@"Agenda Won't Be Deleted");
}
else
{
    NSLog(@"Agenda Will Be Deleted");
}
}
```

Now is the problem that I got the error: Duplicate declaration of method 'alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex'

How can I fix this? I tried some stuff I found here but I still can't make it work. Can someone help me?

Comment: You should be aware that UIAlertView is deprecated..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, like you said, giving a tag allows you to have multiple `UIAlertView` in one single view.

Same goes for `UIActionSheet` or `UIAlertController`

for future reference, even though this is probably a duplicate, simply create your alert like usual and add

```
myAlert.tag = 123; //any number of your choice
```

and in `alertView:clickedButtonAtIndex`

you can find it using a `switch` or some `if's`

```
if (alertview.tag = 123){

// this is my alert

}else if(alertview.tag = 333){

// this is my other alert

}
```

For what it's worth, I suggest using `else if` and not just `if` to avoid the whole method to be read everytime, and order your `if's` by decreasing likeliness of being called.

Note you can also give tags to buttons, views, cells, labels, and just pretty much every outlet you can find.